# Inserting data in background/async task what is the best way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have an very quick/lightweight mvc action, that is requested very often and I need to maintain minimal response time under heavy load.

What i need to do, is from time to time depending on conditions to insert small amount of data to sql server (log unique id for statistics, for ~1-5% of queries).

I don't need inserted data for response and if I loose some of it because application restart or smth, I'll survive.

I imagine that I could queue somehow inserting and do it in background, may be even do some kind of buffering - like wait till queue collects 100 of inserts and then make them in one pass.

I'm pretty sure, that somebody must have done/seen such implementation before, there's no need to reinvent wheel, so if somebody could point to right direction, I would be thankful.

Comment: If I'm correct, then writing to the text file is cheaper then writing to the database. Would it be possible to update a text file on each request to your action method, and then have a background process read that text file and perform a bulk database insert?

Comment: That is an idea, but I guess I would rather use MSMQ with express messages then (express messages means they are stored in memory and in separate process, so in case of restart/recycling iis i would not loose them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Darin Dimitrov's approach although I would add that you could simply use this task to write to the MSMQ on the machine.  From there you could write a service that reads the queue and inserts the data into the database.  That way you could throttle the service that reads data or even move the queue onto a different machine.

If you wanted to take this one step further you could use something like nServiceBus and a pub/sub model to write the events into the database.

Comment: all answers are pointing to right direction in my opinion, but this gave me idea to use MSMQ as storage of "unprocessed insert requests". nServiceBus in my scenario is overkill, but overall I agree, that it would keep things maintainable in case there are many such "pending requests to do something heavy".

Answer (score 7):

You could trigger a background task from your controller action that will do the insertion (fire and forget):

```
public ActionResult Insert(SomeViewModel model)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // do the inserts
    });
    return View();
}
```

Be aware though that IIS could recycle the application at any time which would kill any running tasks.

Comment: I'm wondering about dependencies lifecycle, when using Task.Factory.StartNew. As i understand, task may live longer than controller, or not? If so, won't controller release my object context sooner, than task will be finished?

Comment: @Giedrius, yes, the task will live longer than the controller. That's not a problem. The problem is with IIS that might recycle the application pool.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that will store the data that needs to be pushed to the server, and a queue to hold a queue of the objects

```
Queue<LogData> loggingQueue = new Queue<LogData>();

public class LogData {

   public DataToLog {get; set}

}
```

The create a timer or some other method within the app that will be triggered every now and then to post the queued data to the database

Comment: Hm, should I make it as static variable?

Comment: Yes, you could make it a static member of a class.  In fact, you could tie up the whole thing in a class - timer and all - even within the LogData class itself.  This would make it nice and modular.